# Arrange a string if it's odd

Tags: python

I have a string, I want to be able to move all the digits that appear odd numbers of times in the string to move to the front of the string IN ascending order. The rest of the string remains intact

This is what I have tried till now:

```
from collections import Counter

def getOddOccurrence(myString):
    count = Counter(myString)
    for letter in myString:
        if count[letter] % 2 != 0:
            return letter

myString = "sfsdfsdfs"
print(getOddOccurrence(myString))
```

Comment: The first time you satisfy the conditions and hit `return letter` what happens to your function's execution?

Comment: Why do the `1` and `5` move to the beginning of the string? i.e. why is the output not `'8155544aDc44bd'`

Comment: @Nick 1 and 5 move to the front because 1) they appear odd number of times in the string and 2) you have to arrange them in ascending order once they are found in condition 1)

My bad, I'll add that in the post

Comment: @Maionic then you need to edit the question to say that...

Comment: And to be clear the characters that appear an even number of times are **not** sorted?

Comment: @Mark Correct, characters are not sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is consistent with your expected output:

```
>>> s = "81454aDc5445bd"
>>> cntr = Counter(s)
>>> ''.join(sorted(s, key=lambda c: int(c) if c.isdigit() and cntr[c] % 2 else 10))
'1555844aDc44bd'
```

You can also make some optimization:

```
>>> mapping = {k: int(k) if k.isdigit() and v % 2 else 10 for k, v in cntr.items()}
>>> ''.join(sorted(s, key=mapping.get))
'1555844aDc44bd'
```

Comment: You can simplify slightly to `''.join(sorted(s, key=lambda c: int(c) if c.isdigit() and cntr[c] % 2 else 10)`